# Exception while connecting to Neo4j

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, neo4j

```
Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase, /home/manish/Softwares/neo4j-enterprise-2.1.6/data/graph.db
```

CausedBy: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.XaDataSourceManager@2a792260' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.

CausedBy: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreXaDataSource@23d7c3d2' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see attached cause exception.

CausedBy : No schema index provider org.neo4j.kernel.api.index.SchemaIndexProvider found. Kernel extensions available on classpath:   Class path entries:   /home/manish/NetBeansProjects/ClassLibOperations/store/ClassLibNeo4jOperations.jar   /home/manish/NetBeansProjects/ClassLib2/store/2.jar   /home/manish/NetBeansProjects/ClassLibB/store/3.jar   /home/manish/NetBeansProjects/ExecuteJarFile/build/classes

I am getting the above exception while executing the line :

```
database = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase( DB_PATH );
```

The scenario is something like this :
I have a class library for operation with neo4j graph db named ClassLibNeo4jOperations. This class library has all the references required for working with neo4j. 
Now I am packaging this ClassLibrary as ClassLibNeo4jOperations.jar and adding it as reference in a Console Application ExecuteJarFile.
Now when i am calling a method of this jar file this line 
`database = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase( DB_PATH );` is executed which throws the above mentioned exception.

The JAR (ClassLibNeo4jOperations.jar) is a fat jar ,created using the method mentioned at [How to build fat jar](http://arunasujith.blogspot.in/2011/08/how-to-build-fat-jar-using-netbeans.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have `neo4j-lucene-index.jar` on your classpath.

Comment: Thanks, i added neo4j-lucene-index.jar as reference to the console application ExecuteJarFile . The exception is gone and it's working fine.
Can you tell me why this jar needs to be added explicitly ,even though neo4j-lucene-index.jar and all other neo4j jars have been packed in ClassLibNeo4joperations.jar?

Comment: most likely you have overriden some files inside `META-INF/services` that exist in multiple jar files. Be sure to aggregate their contents instead of overriding.